# just 4 lines from my table

Tags: php, mysql

Hiii

using My/SQL  -- PHP

I have this `php` code with `SQL Statement` that give me first and second names from table players  `joueur`

Now I went to show just the `first 4 lines` from my table

```
            <?php
$con = mysqli_connect("127.0.0.1", "root", "", "bd");
// Check connection
if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
    echo "Failed to connect to MySQL: " . mysqli_connect_error();
}

$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM joueur");
echo '<table style="width:100%">';
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
    // echo $row['nom'] . " " . $row['prenom'];
    echo '<tr>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['nom'] . '</td>';
    echo '<td>' . $row['prenom'] . '</td>';
    echo '</tr>';   
} echo ' </table>';
?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the mysql LIMIT clause...

```
$result = mysqli_query($con, "SELECT * FROM joueur LIMIT 4")
```

Answer (score 1):

Use LIMIT like

```
SELECT * FROM joueur LIMIT 4
```